# How to add same-origin on axios react

Tags: reactjs, http, axios, request, http-headers

How can I add same-origin on Axios (React) like the image below?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;

```js
const headers = {
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin'
 };

axios.post(<url>, <params>, headers))
    .then(response => {
        console.log("Success ========>", response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error ========>", error);
    }
```

`Sec-Fetch-Mode` is one of the Fetch metadata headers (Sec-Fetch-Dest, Sec-Fetch-Mode, Sec-Fetch-Site and Sec-Fetch-User). These headers are meant to inform the server about the context in which the request has been sent. Based on this extra information, the server is then able to determine if the request looks legitimate, or simply deny it. They exist to help HTTP servers mitigate certain types of attacks, and are not related to CORS.

Comment: I tried it but it's still the same "sec-fetch-site: cross-site"

Comment: Okay, can you please provide more details? Image from chrome's dev tool can help

Comment: Yeah, so I am trying to post some signing data from Axios. One of my websites takes the session data and it has "same-origin", but this website doesn't transfer session data from the API

Comment: Both of them do the same Axios post request but one of them doesn't persists session data

Comment: Is there any session management logic implemented explicitly?

Comment: Yeah check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67840980/passportjs-not-saving-user-on-session-in-production-only